# What does "all things visible" refer to in Colossians 1:16?

Tags: genesis, historical-interpretation, colossians

### What does "all visible things" refer to in Colossians 1:16?

All  invisible creatures point to what is created in heaven which meant that all visible creatures point to what is created on earth.

> Colossians 1:16 (NRSV)
> for in him ***all things*** in heaven and ***on earth*** were ***created***, things ***visible*** and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or rulers or powers—all things have been created through him and for him.

Angels were invisible or unseen (like God who is invisible/unseen - Col 1:15) and it needs God to reveal them if they are to be seen.

> 2 Kings 6:17 (NRSV)
> Then Elisha prayed: “O Lord, ***please open his eyes that he may see***.” So the Lord opened the eyes of the servant, and he saw; the mountain was full of horses and chariots of fire all around Elisha.

Comment: @Nigel, Some interpret the "creation" in Colossians 1:16 as *not* referring to Genesis creation. For instance, the socinians interpret it as referring to the new creation (the saints and the new heaven and earth). My question pertains to the nature of "creation" in Colossians 1:16. Was it referring to Genesis or the new creation?

Comment: That seems a crazy interpretation (by the 'some') since the visible aspect of the New Creation (new heavens and new earth) is not yet made. But I now appreciate your focus. (+1 and +1).

Answer (score 1):

In the Old Testament, God alone created **all things** [***on*** earth], which meant 'all things in the dry land' as it was contrasted to all things that are in the sea.

> Nehemiah 9:6 ***You alone are the LORD. You created*** the heavens, the
> highest heavens with all their host, ***the earth and ***all that
> is on it***, the seas and all that is in them. You give life to all
> things, and the heavenly host worships You.

Other biblical texts specified what exactly was made by God on the earth and God made *men and beasts* ( = humans and animals) on the earth.

> Jeremiah 27:5
> By My great power and outstretched arm, ***I made the earth and the men and beasts on the face of it***, and I give it to whom I please.

Genesis  speaks of God creating *plants, animals and humans* in the land (1:24-26).

In these Old Testament texts, we  *consistently* see that he who created all visible things on earth is the same one who created the earth itself.

In Colossians 1:16, all visible things on earth were created ***in, through ,*** and ***for*** Christ which is a language that highly-exalts Christ as the Creator.

Comment: If Christ IS the creator - why on earth is he declared the inheritor of all? You seem to ignore the entire NT to maintain a clumsy construct. Hebrews 1:2
But in *these last days* He has spoken to us by His Son, whom He appointed heir of all things, and through whom He made the AGES - not the world or the universe.

Comment: @user48152, The Bible *explicitly* said that Yahweh inherits Israel (*Israel is his [Yahwehs's] inheritance* - Deut 32:9) and he inherits all the nations (*O God*, *you inherit all the nations*, - Psalm 82:8). In Hebrews 1:2, God created ages (plural, αιονος) through the Son. It's not only about one age (the last days) but the ages (i.e. both beginning and ending) according to the context:  The beginning (γενεσις) was also created through the Son:  ("*O Lord*, *in the beginning*, you laid the foundations of the earth and *the heavens are the work of your hands* Hebrews 1:10).

Comment: Ok, so who 'appoints' Yahweh? You seem to be force fitting what you want it to say. God and Jesus are called Lord - not because they are both God - I'm assuming you understand that basic fact. ie David, the Lord said to my Lord, God promising an descendant to rule forever who was yet to come.

Comment: @User48152, Read Deuteronomy 32:9's context. According to Jewish scholars, El appointed Yhwh to inherit all nations. Confessing Christian scholars interpret this as El and Yhwh to be the same god and thus, Yhwh appoints himself as the one who will inherit all nations. The point is that both Yhwh in the OT and Jesus in the NT were *explicitly* described as "one who inherits" (having been appointed). Jesus being κυριος does not only mean 'adoni' (as in Psalm 110:1) but also 'Adonai' (as in Philippians 2:9-11). Isaiah 45:23, not Psalm 110:1, is the text applied to Jesus in Philippians 2.

Comment: You're digging a shallow grave! Jesus confirmed there is one God - 'the Lord is one'. Not 'one God', but *one Lord* who IS God. He quoted the OT referring to Yahweh. Jesus knew what Deut 6:4 meant without guile. In the same tone he says he is a man, who has a God, who died and was raised by his Father and God. That Deut one is a good verse - it tells us that when all this evil age is done - Israel will still be God's people. From the NT we know all others will be included with them. Rom 1:16 (Which is why Jesus was a Jew.)

Comment: @user48152, Yes. Jesus affirmed monotheism. He also affirmed his oneness with the Father (John 10:29, 10:30-35) as θεος (God) which the original Christians believed (John 1:1, 20:28). Jesus also affirmed his oneness with the Father in early Palestinian churches in his own words: baptise *all* nations in the name *the Father, the Son and the Holy Spirit* (Matthew 28:19). Not the Father *alone*, but also the Son and the Holy Spirit.

Comment: @user48152, You just ignored the earliest theological belief in early Israel (Deut 32:9, Ps. 82:6) and the earliest evidence of High divine Christology in the New Testament (Philippians 2:9-11) which 'equated' Jesus with the Father as possessing the same "name above every name" (Yahweh) in the monotheistic Isaiah text.

Comment: keep digging. The oneness is nothing to do with being God - as many here will testify 17:22, using the Thomas 'proof' is a faint bleep against the NT evidence to the contrary and misunderstands who Jesus was in coming to 'reveal' the Father - his God and our God.

Comment: @user48152, John 17:22 speaks of disciples (and future disciples) becoming united "just as" the Father and Jesus were united. The oneness of believers and the oneness of the Father and the Son were of different types. John 10 was explicit that the Father and the Son were one (equal) as "greater than all" (John 10:29, 10:30).

Comment: (cont.) John 20:17 does not contradict John 20:28 wherein Jesus accepts Thomas's confession that He (Jesus) is "his God" just as John 1:1 does not contradict itself where it says that "the God" was with another "God" (θεος). Each text shows that both the Father and the Son are "θεος" (God). In first century Judaism, we parallel in Philo of Alexandria (circa 50 CE) , a monotheistic Jew, that the Logos was called  δευτερον θεον (second God).

Comment: (cont.) Jesus, as revealer of God "the Father", (whoever sees me sees the Father - Jn 14:9) himself must be θεος (God) like the Father (Jn 1:1, 1:18, 10:29-33, 20:28) because only Jesus has seen the Father (you cannot show someone you yourself have not seen). Jesus knows the Father just as the Father knows him. They have perfect knowledge of each other: *Just as the Father knows me and I know the Father* (John 10:15)

Comment: (cont.) Jesus did not see the Father  by literally looking at his own self (as in Jn 14:9)but through seeing the Father in their unity as "greater than all" (as in Jn 10:29, 30). Jesus knows that he is greater than all, having been one with the Father in respect to greatness. See John 6:46 which explicitly says that *no one has seen the Father except him who came from God. He has seen the Father*). "No man" has ever seen God except [Jesus, who is] the "only God" (Jn 1:18 ESV).

Comment: Fascinating - there's a whole bunch of novel ideas there! Thx for all that.

Comment: @user48152, It's indeed a novelty. Philippians 2:9-11 and John 10:29-30 contain a novel idea unprecedented in ancient Israel, that the Messiah and God were both *greater than all* and had the same *name above all names*. This is the very reason why early High divine Christology is the emerging consensus among New Testament scholars.

Answer (score 0):

Under the influence of Greek philosophy, especially Platonism, the Greeks put a great deal of emphasis on the what was "unseen" and called these things a series of "ideals" - perfect things in heaven that do not change.

Such "ideals" were imperfectly reflected on the imperfect world.

Col 1:16 contains a common (in the Greek world) double hendiadys, namely:

- all things in heaven and on the earth (ie, absolutely nothing is excluded, and almost certainly alludes to Gen 1:1)
- all things visible and invisible (ie, absolutely nothing is excluded)

... thus Paul is using some very extravagant language to emphasize that there is NOTHING that Jesus did not create, either in this earth and what we can see, nor in the spiritual realm that we cannot see.  Then for even further emphasis, Paul uses a an even more extensive list of things so there would be no doubt that anything could be excluded from Christ's creative effort:

- thrones, dominions, rulers, authorities

That is, not only did Jesus create all things, he also created all political power as well (see also Rom 13:1).

There is a simple Greek piece of logic that Paul alludes to here - Christ could not be a created being as this would mean that He would have created Himself.  Thus Paul is simply asserting that Christ is:

- Creator of all physical things
- Creator of all spiritual things, including those in heaven
- Creator of all political power in both heaven and earth

Therefore, Christ is outside of creation because He is the Creator and originator/initiator of everything.

The Expositor's sums this up succinctly:

> Colossians 1:16. Paul now gives the ground for the designation of the
> Son as πρωτότ. π. κτίσεως. In Him τὰ πάντα were created. From this it
> follows that the Son cannot be a creature, for creation is exhausted
> by the “all things” which were so created in Him (“omnem excludit
> creaturam,” Bengel).